# What are some good vim plugins and extensions for java coding?

Tags: java, vim

I have been using IDEs for coding in Java for a while now. For a change, I want to try vim for java programming.

Can you tell me about some good plugins that can make java programming convenient in vim?

Comment: i suggest you have a look at Eclipse IDE - it is free and you can develop and maintain java (or any other) code easily

Comment: i have used eclipse and netbeans before. just want to try on vim. if some good extensions are available, it will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using vim aswell but for PHP development. Still I recommend:

- snipMate - Textmate style Snippet
  plugin with support for many
  languages
- NERDTree - File tree
- Supertab - TAB autocompletion
- Taglist - Tagexplorer

These plugins help rendering vim into a really useful IDE.